# User with no access to child object can create records?

Tags: trigger, profile, sharing, relationships

I have two objects `Parent__c` and `Child__c` with parent-child relationship.
OWD settings for `Parent__c` is Public Read/Write and for `Child__c` it is Private.

The **User1** has Read/Write/Delete/Edit access on `Parent__c` and No Access on `Child__c` object.

I wrote a simple trigger on Parent__c on update to create a child record Child__c.

When I update the Parent record from **User1**, a new child record is created with the *record owner* as **User1** ! 
And for obvious reasons, User1 gets ***insufficient privileges*** error when trying to access the child record that he owns.

How can this be possible? Is this implicit access?
FYI, there are no Roles or Hierarchy defined.

**Edit:** The relationship is Lookup. I tried it through process builder and got the same result.

Comment: Ashwani's answer is correct. You also need to check if the user has "Create" access on the child object and if not, do not create it. The with sharing keyword only restricts access for the class to the record level details based on sharing rules, it does not enforce FLS

Comment: Nice question @ForceMars.

Answer (score 3):

Triggers run on System Mode so, it has access equivalent to system admin so child record was created.

But when you try to access the record, it is user1 context and user don't have access to that object.

Also, when parent-child relationship is master detail you cannot provide OWD access individually to parent and child. Access is controlled by parent. There must be lookup relationship only.

Comment: It has a look up relationship, I forgot to mention. I tried it through process builder as well and got the same results. Don't you think this shouldn't happen? Or is there any valid reason behind it? No documents found regarding this.

Comment: There is a concept of `With sharing` and `Without sharing`. All classes/triggers run in system mode by default.

Answer (score 2):

@ashwani is right.

Trigger always run in system context, it is not possible to run it in user context.

There are a couple things you can do to get close to user mode:

> > Move your trigger logic to a class and use the "with sharing" keywords:
> >     https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm
> >
> > Get the details of the logged in user using the UserInfo class, then query for his/her permissions
> >     https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/06/using-soql-to-determine-your-users-permissions-2.html